# How to delete a path when uninstall a module?

Tags: 8

this is for Drupal 8:

in my hook_install function, i have following code:

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => 'Location',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'route:locator.filters'],
        'menu_name' => 'main',
    ])->save();
```

when I have uninstalled my module, how do remove above defined link?

Comment: If you'll use links.menu.yml file to create the menu item it will be deleted automatically when the module is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hook_uninstall`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/8) and [`MenuLinkManager::removeDefinition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkManager.php/function/MenuLinkManager%3A%3AremoveDefinition/8)

> Removes a single link definition from the menu tree storage. This is
>   used for plugins not found through discovery to remove definitions.